# Regex - The minus sign is not getting caught when processing float numbers in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract 2 numbers from the following string (named **interim**):

```
"location" : { "lat" : 42.3875968, "lng" : -71.0994968 },
```

Here's the code I use in C#:

```
// define a regex for float numbers
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\b-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
// Find matches.
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(interim);

return matches[0].ToString() + ", " + matches[1].ToString();
```

The return is **"42.3875968, 71.0994968"**, without the minus sign for the second float number.

I debugged into the code that can confirm that the "-" is not in the result of matches var.

I've also tested the following regexes, for the same result:

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
(-|+)?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
(-|\+)?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
(-\+)?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
```

Any one have an idea why this doesn't work?

Thanks,
Mylo

Comment: Why are you trying to parse a JSON result why don't you just read it using one of the available JSON libraries?

Comment: I'll offer one more vote of using a JSON library instead of regexes. You're just going to be miserable if you try to do this manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is that the `\b` at the beginning and end of your expression are not what you really want. It will work if you remove them and just use `@"-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+`".

What those do is ensure there is a boundary between word and non-word characters. This is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Should also add that `-` is NOT a word character, which is a common misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is wrong in the code above for the string you're reading.
If you use a regex tester for c# you'll see that the above regex `"\b-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b"` does not include the minus sign.  If you change it slightly to `"\b*-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b"` then you will capture the `-` sign in the match.

Source: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Answer (score 0):

Others say the \b is causing problems.
It could be all you need is something like this:

```
 // ([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*(?<=\d\.|\d))

 (                                  # (1 start)
      [-+]? [0-9]* \.? [0-9]* 
      (?<= \d \. | \d )
 )                                  # (1 end)
```

Edit: 
Comments are broken for my login.
To @JNYRanger

```
 \b*-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b
```

\b* means optionally match a word boundry forever.
\b? means optionally match a word boundry once.
\b means match a word boundry once.

\b is a zero-width assertion, if its optional, usually don't include it.